# MATLAB GUI elements flashing when selecting checkbox

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

I designed a `GUI` in `MATLAB R2014a` with `GUIDE` that have `text boxes,radio buttons,etc`. There are some `check boxes` in my `GUI`. When i check and uncheck this checkbook, other elements of `GUI` will flash(hidden and appear rapidly). It has effect in different elements in every try.

What is this problem and how can i fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post a sample code that replicates the bug? Start removing elements from the GUI to the point you are able to identify what triggers the event.

Comment: Thank you for answer. My GUI is so complex and has 1000 lines. How can I find this trigger? I don't know which part should i put here.

Comment: First of all, make a copy of your project. Then, work on the "guinea pig" copy. Take a check box that makes the flickering and an object that flickers, and remove all the other checkboxes and all the other objects. See if the problem happens again, If it does not happen, start adding your objects back until you find the cause :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem solved in `MATLAB R2014b`. Mathwokrs is using `Handle Graphics version 2` in `MATLAB R2014b`. `HG2` solved all problems. there isn't any flashing in this version.